# Handling negative integers in recursive factorial function in Java

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I have written recursive factorial function in Java. The program works fine, but I want the function to show a message **if the integer input given is negative and quit itself immediately** rather than calling itself recursively.

How is that possible?

Comment: please add your code, so that we can better understand where to make the change

Answer (score 5):

The factorial operation is only defined for non-negative integers. The Java way to handle this would be to simply throw an `IllegalArgumentException` on a negative input:

```
public static int factorial (int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("n must be non-negative");
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial (n - 1);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to answer every question being posted on the site about java right now :) +1.

Comment: Nah, I'll that to Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: Fortunately for me, Mr. Skeet does not seem to overlap with my timezone much :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code snippet before you call the recursive method -

```
if(inputNumber<0){
  break;
}else{
  findFactorial(inputNumber);//recursive method call to find factorial
}
```

Comment: I am not breking from recursion. It just a check before the initial call (may be from main method) the recursive method `findFactorial()`.

Answer (score 0):

If find negative number return function

```
if(n < 0) {
   return;
} else {
   findFactorial(n);//recursive method call 
}
```